# The heat semigroup represented as $\{e^{t\Delta}; t>0\}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Set $\{G(t);t>0\}$ the semigroup defined as $G(t):L^2 \to L^2$ for every $t>0$, where

$$G(t)u=g_t*u$$

and $g_t(x)=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp(-|x|²/4t)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. On the other hand I have seen some notations where $G(t)=e^{t \Delta}$. Exist some relation between $e^{t\Delta}$ and

$e^{tA}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(t A)^n}{n!}?$
The sign $e^{t \Delta}$ even represent the heat semigroup?

Comment: Note that $v=G(t)u$ solves the heat equation $\partial_t v=\Delta v$, and so, $\Delta$ is the infinitesimal generator of $(G(t))$. This formally suggests that we may write $v=e^{t\Delta}u$ (just like how we solve the ODE of the form $y'=Ay$), and the expression $e^{t\Delta}$ can be justified in [various ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586533/different-definitions-of-et-delta?noredirect=1).

Comment: @SangchulLee Does the expression $e^{t\Delta}$ ever represent the heat semigroup?

Comment: Yes, it represents the heat semigroup.